# How do I alter table and change column to identity(5,10)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want do SQL query of alter to change column int type from normal to identity with seed 10 and start 5

how I do that?

I mean something like:

```
 ALTER TABLE Persons MODIFY ID Identity(5,10)

 ALTER TABLE Table3 ALTER COLUMN AutoINC set  Idenity(5,2)
```

to change he's identity

Comment: @Pred the link you have provided is not same as this question.

Comment: @Sachin You are right, sorry

Answer (score 4):

You can't alter the existing identity column. You have to create new column for that.

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD NewIdColumn int IDENTITY (5, 10);
```

Or as you want to put the same name then you can drop the existing column (make sure about your data loss) and then add it again with above statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can't alter existing column as identity column

This link provides the options

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/04d69ee6-d4f5-4f8f-a115-d89f7bcbc032/how-to-alter-column-to-identity11?forum=transactsql